# Add pkt, apt or any other packet manager onto the Oneplus Nord

Tags: magisk, python

On my phone any kind of packet manager is missing. With that - presumably - it is possible to install python on Android. Not even dpkg or rpm are available (curl would be available though). Is there maybe some kind of magisk module or are there any online-ressources available where I can download the packet manager binaries that would be executeable on an Oneplus Nord? I know it's available on other phones, like the Fairphone 4.

Comment: `apt` is Ubuntu's package manger. `dpkg` and `rpm` are also package managers for Linux distros. What is `pkt` and “packet manager”? What's exactly available on Fairphone? What you want to do with a package manager on Android? Did you try Termux? Also see the first paragraph [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205558/218526).

Comment: If you want a Linux like environment install [Termux from F-Droid store](https://github.com/termux/termux-app#f-droid) (not from PlayStore that version is no longer maintained).

Comment: Regarding termux: Yes I tried pkg install python. But then I got an error saying that pkg was not found :/

Comment: The fdroid version was working! Thanks!